# Make total area of div a link

Tags: css, html, anchor

What is the correct way to make the total area of a div a link?

I have multiple `div`'s that are small tiles and I want the total area of the `div` to be a link.

Should the Anchor tag wrap a `span` on the inside or what is the best way to do this?

```
<div class="l-box">
    <h3>Service 1</h3>
    <p>Service description</p>
</div>
<div class="l-box">
    <h3>Service 2</h3>
    <p>Service description<</p>
</div>
```

Comment: not everyone loves this practice , but try to wrap whole `div` with `a`. the problem is that `a` is inline element and `div` is block element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your div with `<a href="#"></a>` and give `display: block;` to `a`

Comment: as per html5 you can define block elements inside `<a>` tag [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)